# Problem with this challenging summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms, binomial-theorem

I'm having some trouble finding the summation of this series.

I tried all I could, but in the end the denominator is creating problem.
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{n} (-1)^r \binom{n}{r}\frac{1+r\ln 10}{(1+\ln 10^n)^r}
$$

The answer is zero but in my book no solution is given.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should show your work and put it in the post.

Comment: Are you sure it's $(-1)^n$ and not $(-1)^r$?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused. I will make sure that this does not happen again. As far as the question goes, yes it was $$ (-1)^r $$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But I am still not able to get to the answer by using the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} x^r = (1+x)^n$$

$$\sum_{r=0}^n r \binom{n}{r} x^r = x \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{r=0}^n  \binom{n}{r} x^r = n x (1+x)^{n-1}$$